# gnuplot live stream with c

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gnuplot

I'm an electronic engineer and I can use C. I'm writing a program that acquires data from an ECG module and send it to another remote pc using an arrays of data through socket. All works properly. My problem is, I need to plot that data in live stream.

To stream data I tried to use gnuplot, everything worked fine but when I put the `fprintf` code in a while loop to refresh the array and write new data it stopped working.

This is part of the raw code I used to call gnuplot in my c program:

```c
FILE* gnuplot = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
while(1) {
    //pulizia buffer e lettura
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    if (n < 0) error("Errore nella lettura del Socket");

    for (j=0; j <= 255; j++){
        printf("%d ",buffer[j]);
    }

    //comunico con gnuplot e invio i miei dati 
    fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-' \n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(gnuplot, "%d %d\n", (r+i), buffer[i]);
    }
    r = r+i+1;
    fflush(gnuplot);
}
```

Why did the program stop working when I added the `printf`, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're doing here, but in any case, elaborating a bit on the "*stopped working*" part would probably be helpful.

Comment: before I put the while loop in the program, gnuplot started normally at the end of my c program plotting my data. I just need to know if I can live stream data to gnuplot in c. this is the first time I do such thing.

Comment: @Christoph - Sadly, here's an on-topic GNUplot question and it was downvoted. I really don't understand some Stack Overflow members at times. On-topic questions are downvoted; off-topic questions are upvoted.

Comment: Just a guess: you might have to send a single line containing the letter "e" to gnuplot after you send the inline data (i.e., after the for loop if the `fprintf` statement) -- otherwise gnuplot doesn't know that it has all the data for the current plot and should proceed to display it.

Comment: Yes!!! you sir saved my day. thank you very much!